# Website looks differerent on different computer(s) running the same browsers

Tags: html

OK. This one has me stumped. It's a "asking for a friend" type of question.
My wife is an artist. She uses GoDaddy as her hosting service to display her work. She uses their tools. She's created a website and several of her paintings are there.
Her computer is a 27" iMac with MacOS 10.15.7 Catalina, retina display etc.

After she's done, she goes to her website and some pictures of her work have the wrong size.
ALL THREE BROWSERS-> Firefox, Chrome and Safari.
And this is after blasting all cookies/caches etc. (everywhere)

When I look using my home computer (Linux Mint) with either Chrome or Firefox, it looks OK.
When I look using my work computer (Windows 10) using Chrome, Firefox, Edge and Explorer, it looks OK.
When she looks with her MacBook laptop using Firefox, Chrome or Safari, it looks OK.

So it's only on her computer that the website looks a bit funky. Strange thing is that when she uses the GoDaddy website to create/modify her own website, the "preview mode" looks OK.

It's only when she actually points any of her browsers to her website does the rendering behave strangely.

GoDaddy tech support suggested the usual "clear cache/cookies/whatever and reboot". Same problem.

I tried changing the IP address and MAC on her computer but there is no difference.

Ideas?

Comment: Graphics card (settings) issue on the iMac?

Comment: Probably needs some @media CSS styles - that 27'' is probably running in some very high resolution. Did you try changing the monitor resolution or just resize the browser window?

Comment: What is the exact model and year of the iMac? If you google, there are some Radeon issues mentioned

Comment: Is it only HER site? Can you upload her images on another site and look there?

Comment: I recommend to check the width of all computers that you mentioned. is all of them have the same width? if not it is natural to have different views. also using relative units for width and size of pictures could be helpful.

Answer (score 0):

it may be of high resolution, the responsiveness of the screen varies between different screen size

Answer (score 0):

This can happen because of many things like -

Using Extensions or other apps in browsers can cause this issue.

Open the site and right-click on the site and click on inspect where you find changes and see the code and refer to your code whether there is any change? if there is a change then this is because of Media queries that have a breakpoint based on the screen width.

If the above ones are not the issue download a fresh copy of the browser and open the site then check and inspect.

Comment: Hmm. That's a good one. Run a diff on the downloaded text. I'll try that. Regarding downloading a fresh copy, I don't know how Macs manage re-downloading Safari but Chrome and Firefox should be easy.

Comment: And yes, I haven't spent time looking at the myriad of other sites but it's only her own URL  (hosted by GoDaddy) that looks funky on her computer. She's created her site with GoDaddy's tools; placed them where she wanted with the sizes she wanted etc etc. In "preview" mode, everything looks fine. She then uploads. Then she points her browser to her URL and some of the pictures have the wrong size basically breaking her carefully laid-out visual impact.

Comment: About says:  iMac is Retina 5K late 2015. 3.2Ghz Quad-coreprocessor. AMD Radeon R9 M320 2GB graphics. But remember, the "preview mode" from GoDaddy is OK so something must be mangling the serving of the page.